# Extends partition using another disk

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lvm

I have A 100GB SSD that I use for root partitions. I have 1TB disk. I'm running out of space on the SSD partition. Can I extends its size using the other disk. I know I can move the /home partition but like this I will lose the benefits of my SSD disk (I have already tested that solution). What I want (if possible) is to have a partition on two disks.

Comment: Since you mention LVM, you should know that this is indeed possible. I believe you should ask a more specific question if you need a more specific answer.

Answer (score 3):

You could have a partition on two disks if you used Brtfs file system or LVM, but creating a partition on two disks will be similar in performance to moving /home to a spinning HDD.

In your case you should probably take a look at [dm-cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dm-cache)

Answer (score 0):

If the "partitions" are really managed within lvm, this is no problem. A single logical volume can span multiple physical volumes. However, you lose control over which disk gets which new chunk of data, so you might lose performance for new parts of files that are otherwise stored on SSD.

I'm seconding Steweryn's `dm-cache` suggestion.